# Yesod Scaffolding function widgetFile

Tags: haskell, yesod

The `widgetFile` is very useful. Why it it not available in the Yesod library?

I do not always want to use Scaffolding site.
I usually would like a one file quick and dirty solution to test ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The scaffolding make you easier to develop a program instead using a single file. In `Foundation.hs` and `Application.hs` you'll find all configurations about auth, static files and also default-layout and widgetFile. You can do it in single file, but is harder and noisy.

If you want to do it in single file install missing deps and copy the widgetFile configuration from Foundation (or Application, i don't remember)